# pytest and multiple test_request_context

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I wrote a pytest set (I'm new to it) that is working but I'd like to make it better. Currently I have, in an example case:

```py
import pytest
from views import application
from views.auth import is_logged_in

@pytest.fixture
def _demo():
    with application.test_request_context(path="/login", method="POST", data={"user": "demo", "password": "demo123"}):
        yield

@pytest.fixture
def _nouser():
    with application.test_request_context(path="/login", method="POST", data={"user": "demo", "password": "wrong"}):
        yield

def test_is_logged_in(_demo):
    res = is_logged_in()[0]
    assert res.data == b'{"username":"demo"}\n'

def test_is_not_logged_in(_nouser):
    res = is_logged_in()[0]
    assert res.data == b'{"error":"Unauthenticated"}\n'
```

I was wondering how could one "merges" the 2 fixtures (it could be more, I have other users with different permissions to test against my DB) in one and pass the parameters `user` and `password` so to create the different context sessions fixtures for the 40 ish tests I have so far.

Perhaps even use something like this for some tests:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(('username', 'password', 'message'), (
    ('', '', b'Username is required.'),
    ('a', '', b'Password is required.'),
    ('demo', 'demo123', b'{"username":"demo"}\n'),
    ('demo', 'wrong', b'{"error":"Unauthenticated"}\n')
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close with your `parametrize` approach. Something like this should work:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'username,password,message', [
        pytest.param('', '', b'Username is required.'),
        pytest.param('a', '', b'Password is required.'),
        pytest.param('demo', 'demo123', b'{"username":"demo"}\n'),
        pytest.param('demo', 'wrong', b'{"error":"Unauthenticated"}\n')
    ]
)
def test_bad_logins(username, password, message):
    with application.test_request_context(path="/login", method="POST", data={"user": username, "password": password}):
        res = is_logged_in()[0]
    assert res.data == message
```

Where the string `'username,password,message'` matches the names of the arguments to the testing function, and the elements of the `pytest.param` correspond positionally.

If you wanted, you could even parameterize the `path` and `method`, if you wanted to make it a more generalized test case.

Comment: I got `@pytest.mark.parametrize` to work in another situation, thanks for that. In my particular question, I was trying to create several `pytest.fixture` (_demo, _nosuer, _admin) with just one piece of code. I'm new to pytest, if it was a simple python code I would use a function or a loop.

Comment: This is accomplishing basically the same thing. If you're dead-set on fixture, just create a private piece of code that is common to each fixture